# How can I insert a character before every word in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, how can I insert a character of my choosing right before or after each word in a string? I have lot of lines that I need to do this for.
Let's say I want to insert the char '%', so it'll look like this:

```
    Before: I am an example string
    After: %I %am %an %example %string
```

How can make this happen? I couldn't fine a solution for this anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?=\b\w+)`
- Replace with: `%`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?=         # start lookahead
  \b        # word boundary
  \w+       # 1 or more word character
)           # end lookahead
```